# Intersection of Compact sets Contained in Open Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

Just wanted to see if my proof of the following is valid:

Let  $\{K_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be compact sets (in some metric space), and let $V$ be an open set such that $$ \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i \subset V.$$ Then there exists $m$ such that $$\bigcap_{i=1}^{m} K_i \subset V.$$

Proof: Suppose not. Then for each $n$, there exists $$x_n \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} K_i \cap V^c.$$
Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence so formed. In particular, this is a sequence in $K_1$ and thus has a convergent subsequence with limit $\hat{x} \in K_1$. Relabel this convergent subsequence as $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Now, there exists $k(j)$ so that $\{x_n\}_{n=k(j)}^{\infty} \subset K_j$, and again has a convergent subsequence that converges to $\hat{x} \in K_j$. Since this holds for any $j$, $$\hat{x} \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i.$$ Since $V^c$ is closed, $\hat{x} \in V^c$, a contradiction.

*And maybe a hint as to how to proceed for a purely topological proof?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s basically correct. There’s a typo at the very beginning, where you meant to write ‘For each $n$ there exists’ (instead of $j$). And you need to pass to a convergent subsequence only once: the tail sequence $\langle x_n:n\ge k(j)\rangle$ already converges to $\hat x$, since it’s a subsequence of a sequence converging to $\hat x$.

For a proof in case $X$ is not necessarily metric, let $F_n=(K_1\cap K_n)\setminus V$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and work in the compact subspace $F_1$. Show that if the conclusion of the theorem fails,

- each $F_n$ is compact, and
- $\bigcap_{k=1}^nF_k\ne\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$,
- but $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}F_n=\varnothing$.

Notice that this argument can be adapted to any family $\mathscr{K}$ of compact sets with non-empty intersection; it doesn’t use the countability of the family.

**Added:** As **Rob Arthan** in effect notes in the comments, you do need to assume that $X$ is a $KC$-space, meaning one in which compact sets are closed, in order to ensure that the intersection of a centred family of compact sets is non-empty; this property lies strictly between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Comment: @Brian Don't you need the entire space to be compact, so that the complement of $V$ is compact? Then you can just use the finite intersection property of compactness...

Comment: @Brian M. Scott yes I was going to ask that ^ as well. What if $X$ isn't compact?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: $F_n$ is a closed subset of the compact set $K_n$, so it’s compact. Then you can work in $F_1$.

Comment: @Anthony: I’ll expand on that; give me a few minutes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No need, I understand what you're saying, but thank you

Comment: @Anthony: You’re welcome. I went ahead and made a small change for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: I finally figured out where the above argument requires the Hausdorff property. In $\Bbb{R}$ topologised so that the open sets are $\emptyset$, $\Bbb{R}$ and the sets $(-\infty, x)$, for $x \in \Bbb{R}$, let $K_n = (-\infty, -n]$ and let $V = \emptyset$. Then each $K_n$ is compact in the sense that any open cover has a finite subcover.  However $\bigcap_{i=1}^m K_i$ is non-empty for every $m$ even though $\bigcap_i K_i = \emptyset$. The proof breaks down because the $K_i$ and hence Brian's $F_i$ are not closed, so you can't apply the finite intersection property.

Comment: @Rob: You’re right that something is required, but one can get away with a bit less than Hausdorff; see the addition to the answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Rob: My pleasure; thanks for spotting that something was needed.