# decreasing sequence of nonempty closed sets in M

Tags: real-analysis

Let $( M , d )$ be compact. Suppose that $( F_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of nonempty closed sets in $M$, and that $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$ is contained in some open set $G$. Show that $F_n \subset G$  for all but finitely many n .

I know how to solve this question. Also, there is a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1509046/549321).

But I just don't **truly understand** this question:
It seems that we can just treat the infinite intersection as a limiting process, we don't have to require $M$ to be compact. In any general set $M'$, if we have a nested sequence of subsets $( F_n')$ at hand, and we know $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n'$ is contained in some set $G'$, then this statement always holds, since, after some $N$, the set $F_n'$ will finally be in $G'$

Comment: @311411  Yes, corrected

Comment: In your new proposition, are you still assuming the $F'_n$ are closed?

Comment: @311411 No... $F_n'$ need not be closed. I don't even consider a topological space. I am assuming a very general situation, in the context of general set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compactness is necessary and your argument is not valid. For a counter-example consider the real line with the usual metric. Let $F_n=(-\infty, -n]$ and $G=(0,\infty)$. Then $\bigcap F_n=\emptyset \subseteq G$ but no $F_n$ is contained in $G$.

Comment: $\emptyset = (-\infty,1] \cap (-\infty,2]\cap (-\infty,3]\dots\,$?

Comment: by replacing n by -n is ok!

Comment: Very very good counter-example. In fact, this example can also be used to show "boundedness" property is necessary for the "nested interval theorem of $R$". However, I'd like to know if it is possible to give a counter example with a non-empty intersection?

Comment: @Beginner Just replace $F_n$ by $(-\infty, -n] \cup \{1\}$ and keep the same $G$.

Answer (score 2):

For a counter-example with a non-empty intersection:

Let $F_n=(-\infty,-n]\cup\{7\}$ and $G=(0,\infty)$. Then $\bigcap F_n=\{7\} \subseteq G$, but no $F_n$ is contained in $G$.